# Cannot find web application files

Tags: webserver, localhost, windows-server-2008, server

I have installed a web application on my computer. As such, to accesses the application, I go to an address like: http://127.0.0.1:8081/SalesCalc/CalcObjects/Calcs.woa/co/2.7.9.5.1.1.3.

My issue is that, having searched, I cannot seem to find the application files. I am therefore wondering where is the root of localhost 127.0.0.1? I have 'show hidden files' as enabled, however I do not see the files in the C drive or anywhere else. When I type in '127.0.0.1:8081/' I am redirected or nothing appears. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hey,any web service has web server check out do you have iis open iis with inetmgr and browse file of web application

Comment: @Hidd3n Thanks, I checked C:\Inetpub\wwwroot but the files aren't there

Comment: are see all sub directory in "wwwroot" ?,in iis management console you see "Application Pool" all application added on there for running web app

Comment: It's strange, I only see Default web Site under Application Pool